# How to let the option menu show vertically on android 4.0+

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, optionmenu

The original option menu on android was horizontal on android 2.3 or older, and vertical on android 4.0 or newer (I don't know what it looks like on android3.0+).

I created a projects which uses the theme: "android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" by default, and the option menu shows vertically on android 4.0+. But when I changed it to "android:Theme.Light", the option menu shows horizontally.

How can I make it vertical again on android 4.0+ without modifying the theme?

Comment: I think u may use a custom theme so that u get the effect as well as the horizontal option menu

Comment: yes, I actually used a custom theme whose parent is "android:Theme.Light", but i don't know how to build the custom theme so that the option menu shows vertically. And that is my question here.